# Visual Studio project template for Blazor with SCSS and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, sass, blazor, bundling-and-minification

The built in Blazor template is too basic for real world apps and does not support any preprocessors except C# compilation.

In Angular, I don't need to care much about setting up webpack, CSS preprocessors, typescript compilations, file watcher etc. Angular comes with everything needed for most SPAs.

Similarly, React comes with `create-react-app`.

**Is there something similar for Blazor?**

---

1. Mads Kristensen's WebCompiler` (the most downloaded plugin) is not maintained anymore.
2. Alternative `Excubo.WebCompiler` dotnet tool is too unofficial, has it's own limitations and requires non-trivial setup.
3. The Task Runner's gulp solutions requires manual setup and there is no standard recommended way. It will become maintenance hell after some time.

Comment: I use WebCompiler.  It works!  I wrote a short article on setting up SASS with Blazor in VS for beginners - not you with 20K points on here!   The link's here for a less experienced programmer finding this question   -  https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Blazor-CSS.html.

Comment: WebComiler does not support latest versions of sass (dart-sass) and is not usable with bootstrap5. If I remember correctly, webcompilerconfig doest not suport wildcards paths, e.g. `pages/**/*.scss`

Comment: Probably true.  I tend not to push the boundaries with CSS.  It's why I commented, rather than answered!  Let someone with more expertise answer.